# Detcting horizontal swipe on relative layout and also properly handle scroll event on the relative layout without any interception

Tags: android, touch, scrollview, gesture-recognition, swipe-gesture

I am new to android development and I am stuck upon following problem. I have been working hard for days and not able to find a solution. In this question I am explaining what steps that I have exactly taken to implement. Please have a look at my procedure and either suggest a solution or an improvisation or an alternative way through which this can be handled.

I want to design a screen which is divided into three parts. The structure of my screen is as follows :

The parent layout of the whole screen is a Scroll-View. The rough structure of the layout file is :

```
    <ScrollView>

           <!-- Other Views (Part: 1) -->           

     <RelativeLayout>        

       <!-- Part 2 -->
        <LinearLayout android:orientation = "vertical">

            <LinearLayout android:orientation = "horizontal">
                   <Button1 /> <Button1 /> </Button3>
            </LinearLayout> 

            <LinearLayout android:orientation = "horizontal">
                   <Button4 /> <Button5 /> </Button6>  
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>  

       <ImageView>

     </RelativeLayout>

          <!--Other Views (Part 3) -->

    </ScrollView>
```

The part of interest is the middle part that is the Relative layout. The Things that I want to 
Implement is that :

1. I want to detect a swipe on this RelativeLayout. So with every swipe to either Left or
     Right I update the the images and the text that is there on these buttons.
2. I want to be able to scroll the screen from anywhere on the screen.
3. To be able to click on the buttons.

Now let me tell you what I have done and the problems that I am facing. To detect the swipe on the relative layout I have set an onTouchListener on the relative layout. The overridden onTouch method is :

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);


        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            return true;
        }


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {   
            if(v instanceof Button){
                v.performClick();
            }

            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();

            float deltaX = downX - upX;
            float deltaY = downY - upY;

            // swipe horizontal?
            if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                // left or right
                if (deltaX < 0) {

                    this.onLeftToRightSwipe();
                    return true;
                }
                if (deltaX > 0) {

                    this.onRightToLeftSwipe();
                    return true;
                }
            } 


        }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Since , the buttons occupy all the space on the relative layout , I had to set this Listener on 
all the inner Linear Layouts and Buttons. To detect the button click and disallow the scroll view to intercept I had to include  `scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` . 
But the problem is that now I am not able to scroll on this Relative layout. 
The Swipe and Button clicks are working exactly as they should but , now it is not detecting the scroll.

If I remove the `scrollview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)` , the scroll is detected but the swipe is not . This is giving a very bad user experience and overall a negative feedback from all of those to who I have shown the application. 
So what i want is that , user should be able to scroll from any point of the screen plus he should be able to swipe on the relative layout and also be able to click on the buttons.

Please Help! Could the possible solutions be like :

1) implementing a simpleOnGesture Listener or Detector? override fling event? Please provide valuable and useful pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use ViewPager to accomplish this. You can learn more about ViewPagers from this link: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

And there is also a sample code in the website that you can see how it works. It allows you to swipe through pages and also scroll down in each page.

So the main.xml file looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And the fragment.xml file looks like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I will try with your solution , I also want to inform you that I tried using ViewFlipper but still I am not getting any satisfactory results, will view pager help?

Comment: I used this solution in my code and it works excellent for me

Comment: I'll check and let you know. Thanks.